# How to align numbering of sentences that do and those that do not have bullet points in LaTex

Tags: latex

I would like to write a paragraph where all the sentences are numbered, but only a few have a bullet point square while keeping the numbers aligned (see image below for desired output).

[image]

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\begin{document}

1. This is an example sentence.

$\bullet$$\bullet$ 2. This is an example sentence. 

This is another example sentence. 

\end{document}
```

In the code above, the 1 and the 2 are not aligned.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use `\begin{itemize}`  with `\item`s when you are dealing with items anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to let latex do the numbering by using an `enumerate` environment and then manually adjust the labels for the bullet sentences:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item This is an example sentence.
\item[\textbullet\textbullet] sentence
\item This is an example sentence.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]